# How can I remove the repeated lines in my output?

Tags: vb.net, indexof, find-occurrences

```
If ArrySentence.Contains(InputString) Then
    Dim index As Integer = Array.IndexOf(ArrySentence, InputString)

    Do Until a >= ArrySentence.GetUpperBound(0) + 1
        Dim position As Integer = index + 1
        index = Array.IndexOf(ArrySentence, InputString, position)

        Console.WriteLine("The word ""{0}"" is at position {1}.", InputString, position)
        a = a + 1
    Loop
```

It's almost done but the problem is the output repeats some of the lines like:
Please enter a sentence
The apple fall from the apple tree
The word apple is at position 2 
 The word apple is at position 6 
 The word apple is at position 2
 The word apple is at position 6

Help!

Comment: Thanks Blackwood!

Comment: Can you provide the sentence you're using to test the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not really understand the reasoning behind your loops. What you want to do is the following: Search for the word in the array. If it exists, print its position. Otherwise exit. Start over.

Here is how I would do it:

```
Dim index As Integer = Array.IndexOf(ArrySentence, InputString)
While index >= 0 'while the word has been found
    'Output the occurrence
    Console.WriteLine("The word ""{0}"" is at position {1}.", InputString, index + 1)
    'Search for the next occurrence
    index = Array.IndexOf(ArrySentence, InputString, index + 1)
End While
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, sorry but I didn't try to look for what's wrong with the one you made.

```
 Dim sentence as String = "The apple fall from the apple tree"
 Dim words As String() = sentence.Split(New Char() {" "c})

 For i = 0 To words.Length - 1
     If InputString = words(i) Then
          Console.WriteLine("The word ""{0}"" is at position {1}.", InputString, i + 1)
     End If
 Next
```